# Magento 2 - discrepancy between documentation and theme files structure on github

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, composer, directory

I am creating a new theme and  would like to start by duplicating the default blank theme and then modify it to become my new theme.

When I checked the frontend developer guides, it indicated the theme files should be within `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/`.

But the structure of magento 2 theme files differs between the github and official magento site download:

- Github has all the theme files within `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/` folder
- Magento 2 official website download has theme files within `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/`. The app/design/frontend/magento/ folder is empty.

So currently i'm a little bit confused about which magento 2 structure should i use - github or official website download.

Any pointers appreciated.

Edit: I have found the same question on [M2 forums](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/different-structure/m-p/23857#U23857) but currently without replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had the same question. I will reference an answer I found on github that gave me a slightly better understanding of the structure.

> When installing via Composer (as recommended for production sites or
>   anyone else wanting stability), Composer puts it under the vendor
>   directory. This is standard Composer behavior.
>        So "vendor/Magento/theme-frontend-blank" is the root directory of the Composer package holding the blank theme. Magento will find the
>   theme over in that directory as well. (This is one of the reasons
>   there is a "registration.php" file in themes (and modules) now. It
>   tells Magento where the theme sits on disk.)
>                So while developing a theme, or if theme is for a local project (not intended to be used across multiple projects), you put it
>   under app/design.
>
> If you decide to sell it on Magento Marketplace for example, there are
>   instructions to bundle it (basically ZIP the directory) and upload to
>   the Marketplace. Other users that download it will have it put in
>   their 'vendor' directory automatically by Composer. The 'vendor'
>   directory holds all code you did not write.

Reference Links:

- [Github Issue Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2577)
- [Magento 2 Theme Overview](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html)
- [Magento 2 Theme Structure Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html)
- [GitHub Source Folder for Magento 2 Blank Theme](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank)