# Magento 2 layout files & folder discrepancy

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, xml

I've read about a folder structure discrepancy depending on how you install your Magento 2 which would cause the `app/design` themes to be moved into a `vendor/magento/` folder.

[Magento 2 - discrepancy between documentation and theme files structure on github](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93374/magento-2-discrepancy-between-documentation-and-theme-files-structure-on-githu)

However my theme files seem to be located in pub/static/frontend/...

which has worked fine for me as far as copying the blank theme & then altering it, however i have come to remove the subscription form from the footer of the site & it seems to be ignoring my layout file.

I've found the `Magento_Newsletter` module using the template path hints & followed documentation to create a `/pub/static/frontend/<vendor>/<template>/en_GB/Magento_Newsletter/layout/default.xml` file within my theme containing:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
</body>
```

So my question is 2 fold:

1) am i wrong to be building a theme in the `pub/static` folder

2) have i placed the `default.xml` file in the wrong folder or am i removing the block in the wrong way?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for question 1 yes you are wrong to build a theme in pub/static folder.

the theme will be create `app/design/frontend/packagename/yourtheme`. when you correct your theme location then xml also taking effect.

here is some tutorial for creating a theme

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: Thanks, can i still duplicate the contents of /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank into the app/design/frontend folder and use that as a starting point or will that not work?

Comment: yes you can duplicate  blank theme contents in your theme.